# Getting runtime error in code for linked list creation and display. Can't figure out how

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct linked {
    int data;
    struct linked *next;
}

*head,*ptr,*tmp;

void display(struct linked *head)
{
    tmp=malloc(sizeof(struct linked));
    tmp=head;

    do 
    {
        printf("%d ",tmp->data);
        tmp=tmp->next;
    } while(tmp->next!=NULL);           
}

struct linked *createlist(struct linked *head)
{
    int i,ch;
    ptr=malloc(sizeof(struct linked));
    //head=(struct linked *)malloc(sizeof(struct linked));
    head=ptr=tmp=NULL;

    printf("Enter number of elements you want in the list!");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    printf("Enter the elements!\n");
    for(i=0;i<ch;i++)
    {
        int ele;
        tmp=malloc(sizeof(struct linked));
        printf("Enter the element %d= ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&ele);
        tmp->data=ele;
        ptr->next=tmp;
        ptr=tmp;
        ptr->next=NULL;
        if(head==NULL)
        head=ptr;
    }
return head;
}

int main(void) 
{
// your code goes here
    head=malloc(sizeof(struct linked));
    head=createlist(head);
    display(head);  
    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is i don't know whether I have allocated the memory correctly or is there any problem in my insertion of node. Please help i am new to this. Please give a suggestion about how do I debug the runtime errors in code how to find them where they are actually. Thanks.

EDIT: I got the error. First I was allocating memory needlessly. To head and ptr. Also in createlist() , I was using

```
createlist(struct linked *head)
```

calling as    createlist(head)
from main().
This was leading to a call by value actually. That's why even after the creation of the list, the display() was not being called just because the head in createlist() was local to the function hence global head wasn't holding the front of the list. So, no way to traverse and that was generating the error.
Thanks for the help all.

Comment: Could you please add the exact error to your question ?

Comment: Also, please review your code because it appears it is not valid. Missing `;` after declaration of the struct, and I am not sure what you are trying to achieve by writing `*head,*ptr,*tmp;`

Comment: that was actually a error in posting. Code had that correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead of your code...

```
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <stdlib.h>

      typedef struct linked {
         int data;
         struct linked *next;
      };

      struct linked *head,*ptr,*tmp;

      void display()
      {
        tmp=head;

       do 
       {
         printf("%d ",tmp->data);
         tmp=tmp->next;
       } while(tmp!=NULL);           
     }

    void createlist()
    {
      int i,ch;

      printf("Enter number of elements you want in the list!");
      scanf("%d",&ch);
      printf("Enter the elements!\n");
      for(i=0;i<ch;i++)
       {
        int ele;
        tmp=(struct linked*)malloc(sizeof(struct linked));
        printf("Enter the element %d= ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&ele);
        tmp->data=ele;
        tmp->next=NULL;

        if(head==NULL){
          head=tmp;
          ptr=head;
        }
       else{
          ptr->next=tmp;
          ptr=ptr->next;
        }
   }
     //return head;
  }



   int main(void) 
   {
     // head=malloc(sizeof(struct linked));
     createlist();
     display();  
     return 0;
   }
```

While creating linked list you have to remember some cases..

1 - At first time when linked list is creating head is NULL and take action according to that
   i.e code given in `if` condition in `for loop`

2 - after head node is got created you have to attach all the remaining node at the end of last created linked list
   i.e code given in `else` condition `in for loop`

And if your creating a global variables then no need to pass those variable as a argument to the function

Global variables are visible to each and every function.